# Second Thread doesn't start until first thread ends

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I haven't used threading in python yet and I'm trying to get a working example going but it doesn't seem to be working. Once my first thread begins my program just hangs while that "thread" does it's work. It appears to be acting as if I just called a function normally. My second thread which is setup to run alongside thread1 doesn't start until thread1 finishes. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
class MainDialog(QDialog, Gui.Ui_Dialog):


    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainDialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        threading.Thread(target=thread1()).start()
        threading.Thread(target=thread2()).start()
    def thread1(self):
        //Do stuff

    def thread2(self):
       //Do other stuff
```

Comment: What stuff are you doing in the thread? If you're only doing very short operations in each thread i could imagine that the second thread can't acquire the GIL until the first thread finishes. But this is only a wild guess.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu Each thread is doing some type of http get request and then saving said request to a file.

Comment: Uh ok. Than they should spent most of time in blocking mode, so they should release the GIL anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new to python so what does that mean? Should this work and you just are not sure why its not or is this something that is just not possible

Comment: 1704863: It should work. For mere on the GIL see [file:///usr/share/doc/python3.3/html/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock]